# This there a smarter way to use php next/previous_post?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a Next/Previous button on my blog, which works great when you start viewing from the homepage and going backwards (in order going back or forward through posts). I use this:

```
<div><h4><span><?php next_post('% &lsaquo;&lsaquo;&lsaquo;',  'Previous', 'no', 'no'); ?></span>
 <span> <div class="right"><?php previous_post('&rsaquo;&rsaquo;&rsaquo;  %', 'Next', 'no', 'no'); ?></span>
 </h4></div>
```

However, every post is split into categories and I have a menu for every category...this is when i run into problems. I use the above code in the single.php, but when you click on a post within its category and click next/previous...it goes to the next or previous post which was posted at the time of that particular post...not category.

Is it possible to do the following: if the user visits and continues browsing the ste normally (viewinng the posts in the order I posted them) then the next/previous buttons work as normal, but if user is browsing via a category, the next and previous buttons will know this and take the user through the rest of those post?

Comment: you might want to post this on the WordPress Stack Exchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have I been messing up the wrong forum? I didnt even know that place existed. The wordpress forums get totally swamped, so thought I would try here...thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be possible that you just append a parameter to the URL if the user comes from the front page. So you had:

http://path.to/blog/article/url/?fromhome=true

and could check it when you call the previous_post method. If it is set, you can modify its parameters so it displays all posts, otherwise you would display only posts from the same category. (Don't forget to pass the fromhome parameter to the next/previous post links!)

Edit: You can use the post_link filter to modify the links in the permalink/next_post methods.

Comment: GENIUS. Nice one afpel, that actually (kinda) makes sense to me. Do you know how I could apply such php sourcery? Thanks man

Comment: When I say that makes sense, I mean I can see now that you mention I would need something like that...Im new to php so really plodding through the process via google and this forum.

Comment: Downvoted because you can't pass $_GET variables through next_post() or previous_post() without some crazy ob_start() and str_replace() hackery.

Comment: You would have to try, but I think you can just append it to the permalink:`<a href="<?= get_the_permalink(); ?>?fromhome=true`.

Comment: Yeah, the next_post() and previous_post() is a problem, but I believe there exists a filter for that, just Google for it.

Comment: But you can't pass them onto the sibling pages by way of next_post(). That only get's you into the first post then you're sol without setting a cookie.

Comment: The filter is called "post_link", play around a bit, you should be able to just append anything you want through it. Can you please remove the downvote, @James ?

Comment: Yea.. that would work. You just need to keep appending that $_GET variable through every link, and also removing it when the user navigates into a category archive.

Comment: @afpel yea, just edit the answer so it's complete and I'll be able to vote on it again.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, im off to find out more about the methods you posted. Apprreciated.

Comment: Im struggling with James cookie method, would this one be easier? This is the code for display categories on the index.php (which links to the category page)

Comment: `<?php
// For each of the categories, create them as category variables
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    // If the category is NOT the cat_name (category name) then echo some stuff
    // So grab all... except where they match cat_name (exclude basically)
    if ($category->cat_name != 'Featured Small') {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>[' . $category->name.']</a> ';
//added [ = [ and ] = ]

 }
}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, unless you set a cookie in category.php there is no built-in method to differentiate if a user viewed the post by way of a category archive. If you want to look at doing that checkout the php function [setcookie()](http://us.php.net/setcookie).

There is an argument for both [next_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post) and [previous_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post) called 'in_same_cat', it's the last argument in both functions in your example, which you've set to 'no'. Just set them to 'yes' instead and the link will point to sibling posts within the same category.

Note, both of those functions have been deprecated. They have been replaced by [next_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [previous_post_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link). The arguments have changed slightly, here's an example:

```
<?php next_post('% &lsaquo;&lsaquo;&lsaquo;',  'Previous', 'no', 'yes'); ?>
<?php previous_post('&rsaquo;&rsaquo;&rsaquo;  %', 'Next', 'no', 'yes); ?>
```

would become:

```
<?php next_post_link('% &lsaquo;&lsaquo;&lsaquo;', 'Previous', 'yes'); ?>
<?php previous_post_link('&rsaquo;&rsaquo;&rsaquo;  %', 'Next', 'yes'); ?>
```

Comment: Good stuff, thanks for all the great info and links James. Im going to try this out tonight and see if it works, I think users might get a bit lost in my site if I dont some how address this. Since its deprecated, do they work just the same ie just replace next_post with next_post_link()? Thanks alot for your input, its appreicated.

Comment: also, since im still a new member, I cannot uprate anybody...so just an extra thanks :)

Comment: Just glad to help, Frank :) I updated by answer to include an example showing how to switch to the newer functions.

Comment: I changed the links over, but they just display the arrows and a question mark so will now go try find the (cookie?) functions to put into my category.php. Thanks a lot for the help, I would never have got the answer to this...thats you done your good deed for the month. Cheers man

Comment: I read that with the cookie method, I need to add the cookie category.php, call it in the header.php and post the new links you provided in single.php. Im struggling with the first, would i call it like this?